# How do I permanently add JARs to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import

I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.1. I have a collection of Apache Batik SVG 1.7 JARs that are used by my projects. Rather than repeatedly importing the same JARs to each individual project now and in the future, I want to import the JARs permanently into Eclipse.

I am guessing that the best way to do that is to import the JARs into the Java System Library (`eclipse/jre/lib`) which is imported into every Java project by default. Is that right? How can I do this?

Comment: If you don't need those libraries for every project, then you don't need them permanently. What you should probably do is use Maven to make a multi-module project to manage your shared dependencies from that

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to do this. Don't add third party jars to system library. System library is not supposed to store them, and they will be exposed to all projects and apps. There is a `user library` concept for this.

A [user library](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fbuildpath%2Fref-preferences-user-libraries.htm) is a set of JAR files. A user library can be added to a projects build path through the build path properties page. The User Libraries preference page allows to define, edit, import, export, or remove user libraries.

Once you create a user library, it can be added it to any of IDE projects.

But it is not a good approach to dependency management to tie dependencies to IDE and/or environment. Better use dependency management and build tools as Ivy, Maven, Gradle.